# EDITAR y ACTUALIZAR registro en TABLAS RELACIONADAS con ELOQUENT laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Necesito editar y actualizar un registro que relaciona a 3 tablas y quiero utilizar eloqunent.**
*La relacion es la siguiente un cliente le pertenece a un usuario y un usuario tiene relacion con un cliente un cliente le pertenece a una compania y una compania tiene relacion con un cliente.*
Por el momento solo tengo el metodo create funcionando. Me ayudarian a implementar eloquent con el metodo edit y update ??
***(estoy comenzando con eloquent)***
Dejo mi codigo a continuacion:
modelo client

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'company_id', 'direccion', 'ciudad', 'provincia', 'codigo_postal', 'pais', 'telefono_contacto'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
}
```

modelo user

```
 public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
    }
```

modelo company

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
    }
```

clientcontroller metodo store

```
 public function store(ClientStoreRequest $request)
    {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {                        
            $user = User::create([
    'name'     => $request['nombre_cliente'],
    'surname'  => $request['apellido'],
    'email'    => $request['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),          
]);

$company = Company::create([
    'nombre'            => $request['nombre_empresa'],
    'registro_fiscal'   => $request['registro_fiscal'],
    'sitio_web'         => $request['sitio_web'],
    'telefono'          => $request['telefono'],                   
]);  

$client = $user->client()->create([
    'telefono_contacto' => $request['telefono_contacto'],
    'direccion'         => $request['calle'],
    'ciudad'            => $request['ciudad'],
    'provincia'         => $request['provincia'],
    'codigo_postal'     => $request['codigo_postal'],
    'pais'              => $request['pais'],
    'company_id' => $company->id
]);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Cliente agregado con exito.']);   

    }
```

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo?